# Undefined variable issue for wp_get_attachment_image_url

Tags: functions

I use below code for profile image in single.php:

```
  <?php
    $author_id1 = get_the_author_meta('ID');
    $user_meta1 = get_user_meta( $author_id1,  'shr_pic', true);
    $mihan_profile = wp_get_attachment_image_url($user_meta1, 'thumbnail');
  ?>
   <img src="<?php echo $mihan_profile ?>">
```

And use below code for change output of galley html layout in function.php:

```
// Customise the WordPress gallery html layout
add_filter('post_gallery','customFormatGallery',10,2);
function customFormatGallery($string,$attr){
    $output = "<div class=\"mihan-gallery\">";
    $posts = get_posts(array('include' => $attr['ids'],'post_type' => 'attachment'));
    $image_alt = get_post_meta($image_id, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', TRUE);
    foreach($posts as $imagePost){
        $output .= "<a class=\"mihangitem\" href='".wp_get_attachment_image_src($imagePost->ID, 'mihan-large')[0]."'><img src='".wp_get_attachment_image_src($imagePost->ID, 'mihan-medium')[0]."' alt='".$image_alt."'></a>";
    }
    $output .= "<div class=\"clear\"></div></div>";
    return $output;
}
```

But in front I have this error:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: image_id in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mihansanat/wp-content/themes/mihansanat/functions.php on line 46
```

Comment: Here `get_post_meta($image_id, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', TRUE);`. `$image_id` isnt defined anywhere. What image is it supposed to be?

Comment: You need to do it inside the `foreach` with `$imagePost->ID`